# is there anyway to remove from a collection based on a .Where() linq clause (.RemoveWhere() ?)

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I see a collection has a .Remove() and a .RemoveAt() method.  I would like to do something like this:

```
  myObject.ChildList.RemoveWhere(r=>r.Name == "Joe");
```

What is the best way to achieve this besides doing a seperate where and then a loop through each item and them calling .Remove()

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`List<T>` has a `RemoveAll` method that accepts a predicate.

```
myObject.ChildList.RemoveAll(r => r.Name == "Joe");
```

Comment: Too bad it isn't on IList<T>.

Comment: Glad I found this before rolling my own.

Answer (score 2):

You could write `RemoveWhere()` as an extension method. But changing collections is tricky and sometimes very inefficient.

Why not create a new collection?

```
myObject.ChildList = myObject.ChildList.Except(
      myObject.ChildList.Where(r=>r.Name == "Joe"));
```

Comment: -1, vague and confusing statements for beginners. The reverse could also be true: changing collections could be much more effective than creating new ones. you should have answered "why not" part yourself.

Comment: Very few things will be faster than creating an IEnumerable<>

Comment: "Create a new collection" is not "cast a LINQ query to IEnumerable". They are very different things. IEnumerable approach also omits a potential need for indexed accesss or repetitive access to `Count()` etc. They need to be corrected.

Comment: The example is overly complex. Instead of using Except and Where, simply flip the equality operator and use `myObject.ChildList = myObject.ChildList.Where(r => r.Name != "Joe")`, assuming that ChildList is  just an IEnumerable. If it is a list or some other type of collection, simply assigning an IEnumerable to it may not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how fancy you need your conditions to be, you could just call Where() but invert all of the logic you would have done in RemoveWhere(). This could get a little convoluted, and is almost certainly a little less efficient than a RemoveWhere() type function would be, but if you want to do something simple and be lazy it would do just fine.